# numpyのバージョンを下げたが、Jupyterから確認するとバージョンが変わらない

Tags: python3, jupyter-notebook

[python - How to fix 'Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False' for imdb.load_data() function? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890813/how-to-fix-object-arrays-cannot-be-loaded-when-allow-pickle-false-for-imdb-loa)
上記と同じエラーが出て困っております。
初心者のため初歩的な質問でしたらすみません。

numpyのバージョンを下げれば解決するとのことですが、jupyterでnumpyをアンインストールしてnumpy1.16.1をインストールしたのですが、バージョン確認すると1.16.3と表示されます。
バージョンを指定してアンインストールする方法、もしくはバージョンを指定してimportする方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: Jupyterの再起動などは試しましたか？ / `numpy 1.16.1` をインストールしたコマンド、及びバージョン確認をしたコマンドはどのようなものでしょうか？[編集]ボタンから追記すると回答が得られやすくなります。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。Jupyterを再起動してバージョン確認しましたら1.16.1になっていました。

Answer (score 1):

コメント欄でのアドバイスを元に、Jupyter を再起動してバージョンを確認したら `1.16.1` になっていました。

---

*この投稿は [@wawon さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54717/numpy%e3%81%ae%e3%83%90%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b8%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%82%92%e4%b8%8b%e3%81%92%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8c-jupyter%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e7%a2%ba%e8%aa%8d%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8%e3%83%90%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b8%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%81%8c%e5%a4%89%e3%82%8f%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment58503_54717) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*